# Maven 3.5.2 cannot deploy artifact to Artifactory with error 417

Tags: apache, maven, artifactory

I'm creating the simple `pom` project as the following:-

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>test-maven</name>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>myartifactory</name>
            <url>
               https://myhost/artifactory/libs-release-local
            </url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>myartifactory</name>
            <url>
               https://myhost/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local
            </url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

The `settings.xml` is

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>central</id>
        <username>my-user-id</username>
        <password>some-encrypyted-password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <username>my-user-id</username>
        <password>some-encrypyted-password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

This project is able to be deployed to `Artifactory 5.8.3` by using `Maven 3.3.9`: `mvn clean deploy`.

```bash
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T23:41:47+07:00)
Maven home: C:\Java.Application\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java.Application\Sun\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

But when I change to `Maven 3.5.2`

```bash
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T14:58:13+07:00)
Maven home: C:\Java.Application\Apache\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java.Application\Sun\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

During the executing the `mvn clean deploy` there is an error as

```bash
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy 
(default-deploy) on project test-maven: Failed to deploy artifacts: 
Could not transfer artifact com.test:test-maven:pom:0.0.1-20180213.064245-2 from/to 
snapshots (https://myhost/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): Failed to transfer file: 
https://myhost/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-maven-0.0.1-20180213.064245-2.pom. 
Return code is: 417, ReasonPhrase: Expectation Failed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
    Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy 
    (default-deploy) on project test-maven: 
    Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact...
    .../0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-maven-0.0.1-20180213.064245-2.pom. 
    Return code is: 417, ReasonPhrase: Expectation Failed.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could you please help to advise?

#### EDIT 1

1. There is no any log printing at `artifactory.log` at that time.
2. The `request.log`

```bash
20180213162947|1|REQUEST|some-ip|non_authenticated_user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.0|401|0
20180213162947|193|REQUEST|some-ip|my-user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.0|200|605
20180213162947|3|REQUEST|some-ip|my-user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.0|200|40
```

3. The `access.log`

```bash
2018-02-13 16:29:47,347 [ACCEPTED DOWNLOAD] libs-snapshot-local:com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml for my-user/some-ip.
2018-02-13 16:29:47,437 [ACCEPTED DOWNLOAD] libs-snapshot-local:com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 for my-user/some-ip.
```

#### EDIT 2

The `mvn clean deploy -e -X` log

```bash
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ test-maven ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=129185, ConflictMarker.markTime=69136, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=36, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=58074, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=20149, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=16, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=960001, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=36, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=76597424, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=1258668}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.8.2:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.15:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.8.2
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.15
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = com.test:test-maven:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = []
[DEBUG]   (f) deployAtEnd = false
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///D:/M2/Repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = pom
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = D:\JavaPrj\sample\test-maven\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.test:test-maven:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\JavaPrj\sample\test-maven\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) reactorProjects = [MavenProject: com.test:test-maven:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\JavaPrj\sample\test-maven\pom.xml]
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://myhost/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://myhost/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local with username=my-user, password=***
Downloading from snapshots: https://myhost/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Progress (1): maven-metadata.xml (605 B)

Downloaded from snapshots: https://myhost/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (605 B at 961 B/s)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file D:\M2\Repository\com\test\test-maven\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\resolver-status.properties
Uploading to snapshots: https://myhost/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-maven-0.0.1-20180213.092946-2.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.018 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-13T16:29:46+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/162M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### EDIT 3

Add the Apache httpd `access_log`.

```bash
my-ip - - [13/Feb/2018:17:40:48 +0700] "GET /artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 91
my-ip - - [13/Feb/2018:17:40:48 +0700] "GET /artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 605
my-ip - - [13/Feb/2018:17:40:48 +0700] "GET /artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 200 40
my-ip - - [13/Feb/2018:17:40:48 +0700] "PUT /artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-maven-0.0.1-20180213.104048-2.pom HTTP/1.1" 417 364
```

#### EDIT 4

Regarding to the [Configuring a Reverse Proxy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy), this generating is not available for the Artifactory OSS version.

1. Here is my `Apache httpd` setting.

```bash
<Location /artifactory/>

  ProxyPass https://myhost:62443/artifactory/
  ProxyPassReverse https://myhost/artifactory/
  SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
  SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</Location>
```

2. The `artifactory/tomcat/conf/server.xml`

```xml
<Server port="8015" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

    <Service name="Catalina">
        <!--Connector port="8081" sendReasonPhrase="true"/-->
        <!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
        <Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="62443" maxThreads="200" URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/path/to/jks" keystorePass="some-password"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>

        <!-- Must be at least the value of artifactory.access.client.max.connections -->
        <Connector port="8040" sendReasonPhrase="true" maxThreads="50"/>

        <!-- This is the optional AJP connector -->
        <Connector port="8019" protocol="AJP/1.3" sendReasonPhrase="true"/>

        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" startStopThreads="2"/>
        </Engine>
    </Service>

</Server>
```

#### EDIT 5

I would like to highlight some significant as the following: -

1. By using the `Maven 3.3.9` to deploy this project against the existing `Artifactory` with `Apache httpd` is worked properly. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I understand that there is no any issue about the configuration.
2. The only changing is the `Maven 3.5.2`.

I've no any clue why this issue occur.

#### EDIT 6

Since there is an exception about the `wagon`

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: 
Failed to transfer file: https://myhost/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/test-maven/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-maven-0.0.1-20180214.065633-7.pom. Return code is: 417, ReasonPhrase: Expectation Failed.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:635)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:557)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:513)
```

I've compared the `wagon` from `maven_home/lib` between Maven `3.3.9` and `3.5.2`, and found that the `3.3.9` use `wagon version 2.10` and `3.5.2` use `wagon 2.12`.

#### Try 1

I copy the `maven_home/lib` from Maven `3.3.9` to Maven `3.5.2`, the `mvn clean deploy` works properly.

#### Try 2

Copy `maven_home/lib` from Maven `3.5.2` to Maven `3.3.9`, the same exception occurs.

#### Try 3

I'm updating the `pom` to use the latest `wagon 3.0.0` as the following: -

```
<properties>
    <my.wagon.vesion>3.0.0</my.wagon.vesion>
</properties>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-file</artifactId>
            <version>${my.wagon.vesion}</version>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-http-shared</artifactId>
            <version>${my.wagon.vesion}</version>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
            <version>${my.wagon.vesion}</version>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
            <version>${my.wagon.vesion}</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

Luckily when I execute `mvn clean deploy -e -X` against the `wagon 3.0.0` there is a `HTTP header/request/response` printing so that I've found the response as

```
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "<h1>Expectation Failed</h1>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "<p>The expectation given in the Expect request-header[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "field could not be met by this server.[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "The client sent<pre>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "    Expect: 100-continue[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "</pre>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "</p><p>Only the 100-continue expectation is supported.</p>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "</body></html>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed
```

Then I google the term `Only the 100-continue expectation is supported.` and found some significant from StackOverflow: [Apache and mod_proxy not handling HTTP 100-continue from client HTTP 417](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889574/apache-and-mod-proxy-not-handling-http-100-continue-from-client-http-417).

#### Try 4

I've set the `httpd.conf` as mentioning from the thread above.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader unset Expect early
</IfModule>
```

At the moment I can execute the `mvn clean deploy` by using the `Maven 3.5.2` properly.

Comment: Anything in the server logs? _logs/artifactory.log_ and _logs/request.log_

Comment: I've added the logs from Artifactory side. Please see my edit 1.

Comment: Are these the logs you get when the upload is denied? That would imply Artifactory is not even called...

Comment: Yes, I've re-execute around 2018-02-13T16:29:46+07:00, the maven still see the 417.

Comment: OK, client side probably then. Did you run maven in debug mode _-X_ ?

Comment: Please see my edit 2.

Comment: Oh, you have a reverse proxy. Did you set it up using the configuration generated by Artifactory ?

Comment: I follow the https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Apache. I don't have that configuration in my hand and will update it tomorrow. Could you please help to point how I can generate that configuration via the Artifactory?

Comment: Look at the documentation one folder above, specifically https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy#ConfiguringaReverseProxy-ReverseProxySettings
This describes how to generate the expected Apache configuration from the Admin UI

Comment: Please see my edit 4 and 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the root cause is

```
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "<h1>Expectation Failed</h1>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "<p>The expectation given in the Expect request-header[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "field could not be met by this server.[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "The client sent<pre>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "    Expect: 100-continue[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "</pre>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "</p><p>Only the 100-continue expectation is supported.</p>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << "</body></html>[\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed
```

The [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328508/813999) advise to remove the `Expect` header by setting the Apache `httpd.conf` as

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader unset Expect early
</IfModule>
```

At the moment I can execute the `mvn clean deploy` by using the `Maven 3.5.2` properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not fix your current problem, you can try other deployment mechanisms like maven Artifactory plugin or deploying from CI. In one of Artifactory's blog posts it is advised to deploy from Jenkins(or other CI in non-cloud environments) to aquire cleaner  pom.xml's. 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin
https://jfrog.com/blog/dont-let-maven-deploy-plugin-trip-you/